# Proof the following graph is loop less

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have a K-regular graph G. Let k = a+b+1.
We want to partition vertices of G into 2 parts A and B such that every vertex in A has maximum number of a neighbor s in A and every vertex in B has maximum number of b neighbors in B.
To do that follow this algorithm:  first we put all vertices in A. Then at each step if there was a vertex that didn't fit the condition, we move it into the other part. Make another graph G2 where any vertex represents a state in algorithm and each edge represents that there is a way between two states. Proof that G2 is loop less so the algorithm works.

Comment: A loop (in the sense of an edge starting and ending on the same vertex) would mean that a state will follow onto itself, which sound impossible assuming that always one node is moved. Do you maybe mean cycle? Please also check your variable names. I assume $K$ and $k$ are the same, and the $s$ in the second line should be an $a$.

Comment: Yes I mean cycle

Comment: I assumed that k=K